# Reverse Timezone offset

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have a timezone name and I want the name of the timezone double its offset.

For instance, Asia/Dubai is +4, I want to reverse that to -4... and have it resolved to EDT

Language: PHP

Here's a sample of what it would look like:

```
$timezone = "Asia/Dubai"
$offset = $timezone->getOffset();
$offset 0 - $offset;
$timezone = $offset->getTimeZone();
```

*Output: EDT*

Comment: Kind of an odd thing to do... might I ask why? And also, how do you want to handle offsets greater than ±6? Should the offset be doubled and then 24 added or subtracted to get back to a real time zone?

Comment: Well, I had the wrong logic. I actually need to reverse the offset so +4 becomes -4. When displaying dates, we add 4 to localize, when searching, we subtract date to account for localized dates. That's how it currently works, don't blame me.

Comment: Can you give an example? This is probably a one-time conversion so speed isn't the primary factor?

Comment: Uh... I still don't understand why you need this? If you want to "normalize" dates to UTC, why not just use UTC?

Comment: Don't store records using local time. That confuses things. Instead store UTC times and display them in local time.

Answer (score 0):

(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)

To get the offset from UTC

```
<?php
$offUTC = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));

echo $offUTC->getOffset(); // in seconds
echo ($offUTC->getOffset()/3600); // in hours
?>
```

To get the time difference between two arbitrary zones

```
<?php
$timezoneDubai = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Dubai");
$timezoneEDT = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"); // note EDT may work, support is not clear

$datetimeDubai= new DateTime("now", $timezoneDubai);
$datetimeEDT = new DateTime("now", $timezoneEDT);

$timeOffset = $datetimeEDT->getOffset($datetimeDubai);

echo $timeOffset; // in seconds
echo ($timeOffset/3600) // in hours
?>
```

I am not 100% sure on what your goal is, but this should help you.  Also feel free to check out more of the DateTime functions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$timezone = "Asia/Dubai";
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone($timezone);
$dateUTC = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
// Offset from UTC in seconds
$offset = $timezone->getOffset($dateUTC);
// Reverse offset and convert to hours
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone($offset * -1 / 60 / 60);
echo $timezone->getName();
```

Comment: Add some description